# Why do I have 2 ground wires inside a junction box and where do I connect the 2nd one?

Tags: wiring, water, heater

On my water heater I just need to know why I have 2 ground wires coming from the inside jct box and where do I hook up the 2nd one?

[image]

Comment: Questions have been raised (see comments on [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/267817/34147) about the white insulation on the lower wire in your picture. Would you please take a look at those questions and [edit] your question (up here) to address them. Without that info, it may be difficult to provide a more definitive answer.

Comment: But. that's actually a very nice photo and info from Tj Lewis, considering this is his first post.

Comment: Oh, indeed, @SteveSh. So many can't be bothered to do that. However, more info _is_ necessary to get a good quality answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your picture is not showing us everything, **you do *NOT* have two ground wires!**

In this picture, the ground wire is pointed at by the green arrow. The bare piece of wire that I *think* you're seeing as another ground wire (pointed at by the red arrows) is actually (most likely) then Neutral wire, note the white insulation hiding further back in the box.

[image]

If you believe that you do have two ground wires in this box (which would *not* be unexpected), then please edit your original question to more clearly show the second ground.

Comment: The white insulation is odd, but it seems to be a tiny piece slipped on the copper wire, instead of the end of stripped insulation.  If neutral(white), it might be stripped enough(if done at both ends) to be okay as ground.  From a question Harper answered last week.

Comment: But wouldn't you expect there to be a neutral wire (white) in the cable coming into the hot water heater?  I see black & red, which make sense for a 240 V heater, but no white.  Do they really make 10-2 NM wire with just black, red, & bare (ground) conductors?

Comment: Y'all may be correct, but we need more clarification from the OP for confirmation.

Comment: @SteveSh  I think i have read on here some of old 10/ cables were different to what we expect these days.  I forget now what the difference was.

Answer (score 1):

the second one connects directly to the junction box to ground it.

All ground wires should be connected together.

Comment: You can see that the upper bare wire is pinched under a screw in the back of the box, that is how you know.